# Cave generation using cellular automata

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics

So i've been implementing a cave generating algorithm for a game that i'm working on.
I'm using a cellular automaton for this algorithm but i've been facing some problems, it doesn't seem to be working properly.
About the cellular automaton i'm using the following rule i found on this website https://softologyblog.wordpress.com/2019/12/28/3d-cellular-automata-3/ :

Clouds 1 rule: **13-26/13-14,17-19/2/M**

Alive cells with 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 or 26 neighbors survive.
Empty cells with 13,14,17,18 or 19 neighbors have a new cell born at that location.
2 states. Cells are either dead or alive. No refractory period they fade from birth to death.
M means a Moore neighborhood.

About Moore neighborhood : consider a 3x3x3 3D grid of little cubes. The interior cube is the current cell, so the remaining 26 cubes around it are the neighbors of the center cube.

And by the way here is the code i used to generate the caves :

```
int cellular_iterations = 50;

srand((ax * CX) + (ay * CY) + (az * CZ));
for (int x = 0; x < CX+2; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < CY+2; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < CZ+2; z++)
        {
            float rd = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
            if (rd > 0.5f)  cellules[x][y][z] = 1;
            else    cellules[x][y][z] = 0;

            if (ay == (-SCY/2)) cellules[x][y][z] = 1;
        }

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> cellules_(CX + 2, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(CY + 2, std::vector<int>(CZ + 2, -1)));
for (int i = 0; i < cellular_iterations; i++)
{
    for (int x = 1; x < CX+1; x++)
        for (int y = 1; y < CY+1; y++)
            for (int z = 1; z < CZ+1; z++)
            {
                bool isalive = false;
                int alive_blocks = 0;
                for (int x_ = -1; x_ < 2; x_++)
                    for (int y_ = -1; y_ < 2; y_++)
                        for (int z_ = -1; z_ < 2; z_++)
                        {
                            if (!(x_ == 0 && y_ == 0 && z_ == 0))
                            {
                                alive_blocks += (cellules[x+x_][y+y_][z+z_] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(cellules[x + x_][y + y_][z + z_] == 1)   isalive = true;
                            }
                        }
                if (isalive && alive_blocks >= 13)
                {
                    cellules_[x][y][z] = 1;
                }
                else if (!isalive && ((13 <= alive_blocks && alive_blocks <= 14) || (17 <= alive_blocks && alive_blocks <= 19)))
                {
                    cellules_[x][y][z] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    cellules_[x][y][z] = 0;
                }
            }
    for (int x = 0; x < CX + 2; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < CY + 2; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < CZ + 2; z++)
            {
                cellules[x][y][z] = cellules_[x][y][z];
                if (ay == (-SCY/2)) cellules[x][y][z] = 1;
            }
}
```

Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?? because it's not giving me the expected results.

Comment: Do you have a specific error, or are the results simply not what you expected?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: You may need to have better handling of things at the edges. Your initial setup sets the edges to random values (like the rest of the area), but the `cellules_` edge entries never change from -1, so on subsequent iterations (after these have been copied into `cellules`) all the edges count as dead cells (because you're consistently checking the cell value for `1` to see if it is alive).

Comment: What is the `if (ay == (-SCY/2))` check supposed to be doing? If that condition is true you'll set every cell in you grid to be alive.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the if statement checks for the last layer of the world and then assigns 1 to it so the player can never go below the world